# White screen when loading swf in https

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ssl, flash-builder

When loading in https, my swf flashes for split second and then it turns into a blank white screen. It seems the flash is loading while doing tihs. When the user manually press browser refresh button it will finally displays. What causes this?

To reproduce this issue, open https://www.vantagefx.com/webtrader in a clean browser environment to avoid browser caching (eg: Google Chrome Incognito mode)

The problem doesn't happen when the same swf is loaded via http, eg: http://www.enfinium.com.au/webtrader. (Those are same swf, only different branding)

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.vantagefx.com/webtrader throws an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::rawChildren_removeChild()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2143]
at mx.managers::SystemChildrenList/removeChild()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemChildrenList.as:163]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDoneHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2645]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/displayClassCompleteHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:582]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at libs.Preloader::XPreloader/endClose()[C:\Users\GerryT\Documents\git_repositories\WebTrader\src\libs\Preloader\XPreloader.as:237]
at libs.Preloader::XPreloader/closeEffectTimer_timer()[C:\Users\GerryT\Documents\git_repositories\WebTrader\src\libs\Preloader\XPreloader.as:251]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: It also behaves as the OP describes: I see the app for a moment, the error is thrown, and then the page is blank. @gerrytan, you would see this too if you were using the debug Flash Player.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can confirm this is the cause of the problem. Wasn't aware uncaught exception would cause this.